# How to bind spgrideview using linqdatasource?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, visual-web-part

How to bind **spgrideview** using **linqdatasource** ?

Comment: You can bind it normally, what problems are you facing?

Comment: I dont know how to bind using linqdatasource. I know how to bind with objectdatasource  with returning datatable .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP:

```
<SharePoint:SpGridView datasourceid = "<linqdatasourceid>">
```

OR

C#:

```
MySpGridView.datasourceid = "<linqdatasourceid>"
```

If you are asking how to use a LinqDataSource see [This MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb547113%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

You can connect the linq datasource to an entity class and use linq on it from c# or asp.

Personally when I connect sharepoint data to a SpGridView I just set the `.DataSource` property in the behind code with my data and rebind as needed.